How do I convert the attribute "popupinfo" in a layer converted from a KML, into attributes in said layer
I'm working in the latest edition of ArcGIS Pro (Version 3.4.0) and I pulled in some publicly available data for street centerlines, which was published in both KML and shapefile format. Unfortunately, the shapefiles were incomplete so I was forced to convert the KML to a layer, which is where the problem begins.
In the layer there is an attribute that's called "popupinfo" which is what pops up when you click on the KML, aka the attribute table of the KML which has everything I need in it. However when it's converted to a layer, this table is put into a table stuck inside HTML code and it cannot be scanned by any of the tools I need to work with in ArcGIS.
Is there any way for me to add these attributes from the popupinfo field to the attributes in the layer? Or do I need to separately extract it and add it in using a join or python?
You can find the data I'm using at this URL. It's "RBC_Roads.kmz" in the "DATA" folder.

Do you have access to QGIS? The KML Tools plugin has a "Expand HTML description field" processing tool.

I once wrote a Python script tool for this. The function that does the bulk of the work looks like this:
import arcpy, os, re


def FieldsAndValuesFromPopup(popupText):
    attrNames = []
    attrValues = []
    try:
        popupText = re.sub("<tr.*?>", "<tr>", popupText)
        popupText = re.sub("<td.*?>", "<td>", popupText)
    except Exception as e:
        arcpy.AddError("Bad popup text:\n{}".format(popupText))
        raise e
    tableRows = [re.sub("</tr>.*", "", tr, flags=re.DOTALL).strip() for tr in popupText.split("<tr>")]
    tableRows = tableRows[1:]  #  Ignore everything before the first <tr>
    for tr in tableRows:
        tableDatas = [td.replace("</td>", "").strip() for td in tr.split("<td>")]
        tableDatas = [td for td in tableDatas if len(td)]
        if len(tableDatas) != 2:
            continue
        attrNames.append(tableDatas[0])
        attrValues.append(tableDatas[1])
    return (attrNames, attrValues)

Pass the KML popup text to this function, and it will return two lists of attribute names and attribute values.  These can then be used to create attributes and populate them with values.
The rest of the script is implementation-dependent and specific to the environment I was working in, so I've not included it here.  But it used a SearchCursor to find all the popup values and create the fields.  Then it used an UpdateCursor to populate the values in those fields.  Not terribly efficient, but it was effective.
